Unexpected Results After Dropping and Recreating a Collection in Milvus
I am using the Milvus Docker image (milvusdb/milvus:v2.4.5) along with pymilvus version 2.4.5. After dropping a collection named 'demo' and then recreating it, I am experiencing unexpected behavior with the search results. When I insert data into the collection and then perform a search, the output is an empty array.
However, if I create the collection without dropping it first, the search yields correct results. I would like to understand the proper procedure for dropping and recreating a collection in Milvus and whether this behavior is intended or a potential bug.
